# Bootstrap Carousel doesn't show all the thumbnails

Tags: html, css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

My bootstrap carousel is unable to show all the thumbnail images.
I have 4 images, but it only shows 3 of the images, the last one being an empty image on my website.

Here is my code:

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">

    <div class="item active">
      <img src="Images/womenad1.jpg">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="Images/womenad2.jpg">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="Images/womenad3.jpg">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="Images/womenad4.jpg">
    </div>

  </div>

  <!-- Left and right controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>

</div>
```

Please advise.

Comment: I applied your code locally and i can see 4 images.

Comment: I don't see problem on the code. Maybe the image link itself is the problem or others beyond this code.

Comment: I thing the womenad4.jpg is missing from your images folder OR Check the spelling and extension.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what went wrong, but I changed the size of all my thumbnails to be almost the same width and height. This solved the problem.

Answer (score -2):

Is womenad4.jpg surely in the Images directory? 
And also check whether it is a png or other file type.

This might work otherwise..

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="Images/womenad1.jpg" alt="Chania">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="Images/womenad2.jpg" alt="Chania">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="Images/womenad3.jpg" alt="Flower">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="Images/womenad4.jpg" alt="Flower">
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Left and right controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```